# What are theta, phi and lambda in cu1(theta, ctl, tgt) and cu3(theta, phi, lam, ctl, tgt)? What are the rotation matrices being used?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, matrix-representation

I was reading the documentation for [qiskit.QuantumCircuit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/ja/_autodoc/qiskit.QuantumCircuit.html) and came across the functions `cu1(theta, ctl, tgt)` and `cu3(theta, phi, lam, ctl, tgt)`. Looking at the names they seem to be controlled rotations. `ctrl` represents the controlled qubit and `tgt` represents the target qubit. However, what are `theta`, `lambda` and `phi`? They're rotations about which axes? Also, which rotation matrices are being used for `cu1` and `cu3`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [IBM Q Documentation](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/tutorial?sectionId=full-user-guide&page=002-The_Weird_and_Wonderful_World_of_the_Qubit~2F004-advanced_qubit_gates) (the link is hard to find) here is the definition of the generic gate:
$$
U(\theta, \phi, \lambda) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -e^{i\lambda} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\
e^{i\phi} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & e^{i(\lambda + \phi)} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

With this gate, they define the following gates:
$$
\begin{split}
U_1(\lambda) &= U(0, 0, \lambda) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda}
\end{pmatrix} \\
U_2(\phi, \lambda) &= U\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \psi, \lambda\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -e^{i\lambda} \\ e^{i\phi} & e^{i(\lambda+\phi)}
\end{pmatrix} \\
U_3(\theta, \phi, \lambda) &= U(\theta, \phi, \lambda) = \text{see above}
\end{split}
$$

These gates are the basis (with `CX`) of the IBM Q online backends (i.e. the real chips).

The `cu1` and `cu3` are the controlled operations associated with the matrices above.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your 1st question:

The $\theta$, $\phi$, and $\lambda$ are just different representations here, to show that they are independent, just the angle $\theta$ that we study in the rotation gates.
$R_x(\theta)$, $R_y(\theta)$, and $R_z(\theta)$

You can understand it by decomposing this U gate
\begin{equation}
U3(\theta, \phi, \lambda) = R_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)R_z(\lambda)\\
U1(\theta) = R_z(\theta)
\end{equation}

Finally, convert them to control gates. Here, I am just explaining, what are $\theta$, $\phi$, and $\lambda$?

Now, In response to your 2nd question:

U is a gate with parameters so until unless you provide parameters there is no specific axis of rotation.

Finally,

\begin{equation}
U1(\lambda) = U3(0,0,\lambda)\\
cU1 = |0\rangle\langle0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes U1
\end{equation}

Similar for U3.