# Qiskit gates in LaTeX representation: notation meaning

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, terminology-and-notation

I started working in Qiskit, and here is an example of how gates of a circuit are represented graphically in LaTeX format:

[image: Qiskit code]

Obviously, $R_y(\theta)$, is a y rotation by a certain angle. But all the other gates look like $U_i(x,y,z)$, and I don't know how what they actually do. What is their matrix representation? What do the numbers $i,x,y$ and $z$ mean?

Comment: Hi, Samuel. I think Nelimee's answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2708) completely addresses your question. Let me know if there's anything missing in that answer; I will then reopen your question.