# How to quickly calculate the custom U3 gate parameters $\theta, \phi$ and $\lambda$ for any unitary?

Tags: programming, qiskit, resource-request, ibm-q-experience

In IBM Qiskit and Quantum Experience, the custom `U3` gate is defined as

$$
U(\theta, \phi, \lambda) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -e^{i\lambda} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\
e^{i\phi} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & e^{i(\lambda + \phi)} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there any way to quickly obtain the parameters $\theta, \phi$ and $\lambda$ for any arbitrary $2\times 2$ unitary $X$? I know it's possible to write up a lengthy program which could do this, but is there already a similar program out there? Any of the common programming languages would be fine.

---

<sup>**Related**: [What are theta, phi and lambda in cu1(theta, ctl, tgt) and cu3(theta, phi, lam, ctl, tgt)? What are the rotation matrices being used?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/what-are-theta-phi-and-lambda-in-cu1theta-ctl-tgt-and-cu3theta-phi-lam)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Python - Sympy

It could be done in python using `sympy`. I am not really an expert and maybe there could be ways to optimize this, but the following works fine for me.
Assuming you have the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$$

My program

```
from sympy import *

def get_angles(a, b, c, d):
    if im(a) == 0:
        print("Not phasing")
        s = _compute_angles(a, b, c, d)
        res = _final_constraint(s)
        if len(res) != 0:
            return res
    print("Phasing by first element...")
    matr = Matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])
    ph = arg(matr[0])
    matr_phased = simplify(matr/(cos(ph) + I*sin(ph)))
    s = _compute_angles(matr_phased[0], matr_phased[1], matr_phased[2],
                        matr_phased[3])
    return _final_constraint(s)


def _compute_angles(a, b, c, d):
    theta, phi, lamb = symbols('\\theta \\phi \\lambda', real=True)
    a_eq = Eq(cos(theta / 2), a)
    b_eq = Eq(-exp(I * lamb) * sin(theta / 2), b)
    c_eq = Eq(exp(I * phi) * sin(theta / 2), c)
    d_eq = Eq(exp(I * (phi + lamb)) * cos(theta / 2), d)
    return solve([a_eq, b_eq, c_eq, d_eq], [theta, phi, lamb], dict=True)


def _final_constraint(result):
    res = []
    for sol in result:
        to_add = True
        for k, v in sol.items():
            if str(k) == '\\theta' and (v < 0 or v > pi):
                to_add = False
                break
            elif str(k) == '\\phi' and (v < 0 or v >= 2 * pi):
                to_add = False
                break
        if to_add:
            res.append(simplify(sol))
    return res
```

Note that for Qiskit `U` matrix you should only check if the first number is imaginary and, if it so, you could divide the whole matrix by it. It is not really necessary to divide by the determinant, provided that the matrix represent indeed a valid quantum gate (or, said differently, the magnitude are all less than 1).

To avoid Python evaluation of fractions, instead of simply using `1/2` a common trick is to use `S(1)/2` or `Rational(1,2)`

### Examples

#### A generic unitary

`get_angles(sqrt(S(1)/5), sqrt(S(4)/5), -sqrt(S(4)/5), sqrt(S(1)/5))`
returns

$$
\left[ \left\{ \lambda : \pi, \  \phi : \pi, \  \theta : 2 \operatorname{acos}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} \right)}\right\}\right]
$$

#### Pauli-Y matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

`get_angles(0, -I, I, 0)` returns 
$$
\left[ \left\{ \lambda : \frac{\pi}{2}, \  \phi : \frac{\pi}{2}, \  \theta : \pi\right\}\right]
$$

#### $\sqrt{NOT}$

```
sqnot = Matrix([[1+I, 1-I], [1-I, 1+I]]) * Rational(1,2)
get_angles(sqnot[0], sqnot[1], sqnot[2], sqnot[3])
```

$$
\left[ \left\{ \lambda : \frac{\pi}{2}, \  \phi : \frac{3 \pi}{2}, \  \theta : \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}\right]
$$

#### Matrix of Sanchayan Dutta [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6237/4848)

`get_angles(-1/sqrt(2), I/sqrt(2), I/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2))`
$$
\left[ \left\{ \lambda : \frac{\pi}{2}, \  \phi : \frac{3 \pi}{2}, \  \theta : \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}\right]
$$

Comment: Nice! Note that there are some edge cases though. Like when $a$ lies outside the range of $\cos(\theta/2)$. Moreover, you'd have to place the restrictions $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi <2\pi$.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta which edge cases are you referring to? For the restrictions, you are right. I have not been able to place them yet, if I simply those equations in the `solve` function `sympy` returns an empty result. As I said, I am not really an expert on `sympy`, but I'll try to figure out something.

Comment: Say, your code wouldn't work for `1/2[[1+i,1-i],[1-i,1+i]]` i.e. the square root of NOT.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta well, I think this is a limitation of `Qiskit`. If I remember correctly, the square root of not is implemented by an $R_Z(\pi/2)$ sandwiched between two `H` gates. I don't know if they can implement it directly.

Comment: Not quite. There's a [trivial solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239947/how-to-find-the-value-with-which-i-need-to-divide-a-unitary-matrix-such-that-its/3239968#3239968) for this...

Comment: @SanchayanDutta but the matrix used is different from (the modern versions of) Qiskit. Can the previous mathematica answer solve this instance of the problem?

Comment: Yep, my Mathematica solution solves this problem. Not sure which matrix you're talking about.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta ok, now I got what you were trying to say, adding a global phase. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed...global phase.

Comment: Well, I ended up writing a 50 line code program for a task which I thought to be more trivial. Anyway, I'll post my solution in a few minutes.

Comment: Great! But any idea why it doesn't show the first and third solution sets in terms of Pi?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I think it's a limitation of the `solve` method. I'll try with other `sympy` solver. Anyway, could you double check if my results are the same than yours? I have not access to mathematica. Note also that I edited my answer, there were a stupid bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94153/discussion-between-sanchayan-dutta-and-tigerjack89).

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I think this is the final version

Answer (score 4):

## Qiskit

You can also do this directly from Qiskit using this piece of code

```
from qiskit.quantum_info.synthesis import euler_angles_1q 
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm 
import numpy as np 

x_matrix = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]) 
x_90_matrix = sqrtm(x_matrix)
# Returns (theta, phi, lambda) 
euler_angles_1q(x_90_matrix)                                                                                 
Out[4]: (1.5707963267948966, -1.5707963267948966, 1.5707963267948966)

an_matr = np.array([[-1/sqrt(2), 1j/sqrt(2)], [1j/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2)]]
euler_angles_1q(an_matr)                                                                                                      
Out[14]: (1.5707963267948966, 4.71238898038469, 1.5707963267948966
```

Thanks to the Qiskit slack channel for this hint. For those interested, [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/6125f5cbbf322268f53328f23c0be348c4fe0771/qiskit/quantum_info/synthesis/two_qubit_decompose.py) there is the source code of the `euler_angles_1q` function.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica

With help from [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199113/63834), I managed to put this together (assuming `Z` is our 2 × 2 unitary):

```
U = {{Cos[\[Theta]/
     2], -E^(I \[Lambda]) Sin[\[Theta]/
      2]}, {E^(I \[Phi]) Sin[\[Theta]/2], 
   E^(I (\[Lambda] + \[Phi])) Cos[\[Theta]/2]}};
FullSimplify[
 Reduce[Z == U && 0 <= \[Phi] < 2 Pi && 0 <= \[Theta] <= Pi && 
   0 <= \[Lambda] < 2 Pi, {\[Theta], \[Phi], \[Lambda]}]]
```

Note that you'll need to define `Z` beforehand. Say, if $Z=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{i}{\sqrt 2} \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt 2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix}$, the corresponding code is:

```
Z = {{-1/Sqrt[2], I/Sqrt[2]}, {I/Sqrt[2], -1/Sqrt[2]}};
Z = Z/Sqrt[Det[Z]];
Z = Simplify[Z/Exp[I Arg[Z[[1, 1]]]]];
U = {{Cos[\[Theta]/
     2], -E^(I \[Lambda]) Sin[\[Theta]/
      2]}, {E^(I \[Phi]) Sin[\[Theta]/2], 
   E^(I (\[Lambda] + \[Phi])) Cos[\[Theta]/2]}};
FullSimplify[
 Reduce[Z == U && 0 <= \[Phi] < 2 Pi && 0 <= \[Theta] <= Pi && 
   0 <= \[Lambda] < 2 Pi, {\[Theta], \[Phi], \[Lambda]}]]
```

and the solution is:

```
2 \[Theta] == \[Pi] && 2 \[Phi] == 3 \[Pi] && 2 \[Lambda] == \[Pi]
```

Note that the matrix $U(\pi/2,3\pi/2,\pi/2)$ differs by a phase factor from $Z$. This is because of the transformation due to

```
Z = Z/Sqrt[Det[Z]];
Z = Simplify[Z/Exp[I Arg[Z[[1, 1]]]]];
```

which is meant to deal with those cases where $Z_{11}$ exceeds the range of $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$. I've discussed about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3239968). Remember that $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$  and $0 \leq \phi <2\pi$ according to the [documentation](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/tutorial?sectionId=full-user-guide&page=002-The_Weird_and_Wonderful_World_of_the_Qubit~2F004-advanced_qubit_gates).

---

<sup>**P.S**: You can run this code on [Mathematica Cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com) now cf. [Wolfram Releases the Wolfram Engine for Developers!!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30332)</sup>

Comment: what about taking the traces $\mathrm{Tr}(U\sigma_i)$ for the different Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ to get the components of the matrix and then just applying $\arccos$ etc where necessary? (I'm asking in case you already considered that but it didn't suit you for some reason)

Comment: I didn't think about that before. Anyway, the traces you mention don't really look "nice". Say $\mathrm{Tr}(U\sigma_1) = -e^{i\lambda}\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})+e^{i\phi}\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$. There is more than one variable involved in each such trace; a simple arcsin/arccos wouldn't work...at least the way I'm seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function `euler_angles_1q` is now deprecated. It has been superseded by the 'qiskit.quantum_info.OneQubitEulerDecomposer' class which provides the same functionality. See https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.19/release_notes.html