# How can I build up an arbitrary quantum circuit given a certain unitary matrix operation?

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, unitarity, universal-gates

Suppose I want to put a qubit whose initial state is $|0\rangle$ to the final state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|0\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|1\rangle$.

Well, in that case, the unitary matrix that performs such operation is given by:
$$U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix}1&-\sqrt{2}\\ \sqrt{2} & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$
So the question is, how can I build a quantum circuit with the usual quantum gates (X, Y, Z, etc) which reproduces this behavior?

Comment: You can implement this using a `U3` gate, see how to do this in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6236/how-to-quickly-calculate-the-custom-u3-gate-parameters-theta-phi-and-lamb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $Ry$ (y-rotation gate). Its general matrix is

$$
Ry(\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -\sin(\theta/2) \\
\sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Applying the gate on $|0\rangle$ state, you get a state

$$
|\psi\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + \sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle
$$

Hence $\cos(\theta/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and

$$
\theta = 2\arccos\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Big) = 1.910633.
$$

You can validate that such setting of $\theta$ gets your matrix $U$.