# How to find angle for Pauli-Z in U3

Tags: qiskit, pauli-gates

What are the angles (lambda, phi and theta) for Pauli-Z gate in U3 ?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6236/55. If that doesn't answer your question, please provide more context and details (by editing the question accordingly, *not* in the comments). For example, what do you mean exactly with "find angle" here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OneQubitEulerDecomposer`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.OneQubitEulerDecomposer.html) class as follows:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import OneQubitEulerDecomposer

decomposer = OneQubitEulerDecomposer('U3')

theta, phi, _lambda = decomposer.angles(ZGate().to_matrix())
print(theta, phi, _lambda)
```

Comment: I like this solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn rewrite your Pauli-Z into a U3 with [`transpile`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html):

```
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.opflow import Z
circuit_u3 = transpile(Z.to_circuit(), basis_gates=['u3'])
circuit_u3.draw()
```

```
   ┌───────────┐
q: ┤ U3(0,0,π) ├
   └───────────┘
```

There you have the [$\texttt{U3}(\theta, \phi, \lambda)$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U3Gate.html), $\theta=0$, $\phi=0$, and $\lambda=\pi$.