# How are $\theta, \phi$ and $\lambda$ for the U3 gate derived in Abhijith et al. 2018?

Tags: programming, density-matrix, matrix-representation

I am looking to implement Quantum PCA from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03719.pdf) paper (page 62). They have their code on [Github](https://github.com/lanl/quantum_algorithms/blob/master/QASM/Quantum_PCA.qasm).

I have gone through the paper multiple times but failing to understand how they got numbers (for theta, phi and lambda) on line 6, 7, 10, 11, 12 and 13. I understand classical pre-processing where they calculate covariance matrix, density matrix and purify density matrix. I fail to understand how they get those numbers (for theta, phi and lambda) from purified density matrix.

If anyone can point me on how to calculate theta, phi and lambda.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6236/55

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that post, however, the output that I get doesn't match numbers in Github. So, trying to understand whole procedure to see what am I missing.

Comment: Do you know what the value of $|\psi\rangle$ is?  It looks like it's just creating two copies, as described in the text.